# Copy media/catalog to magento 2

Tags: migration, media-images

We are in one of the last steps of migrating to Magento2 and we only need to copy the media/catalog images to Magento2. I would like to know if I need to flush the image cache first before copying to Magento2. We need to copy the images from a live magento1 shop.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

No you don't. Just copy the original images, not the cached images. Make sure that it will not override the existing images.

Magento 1 and 2 have the same image structure, zip entire `media/catalog` folder in Magento 1 then extract/merge it into `pub/media/catalog` in Magento 2. After that, remove all `cache` folders inside `catalog`. That's all.

Comment: Hi Jamy, thanks! Do you zip the folder in sftp or in terminal?

Comment: I prefer terminal (putty) to FileZilla. Every command is executed much faster in the terminal.